# Как в JQuery работать с элементом, который создается динамически?

Tags: jquery

Создаваемый элемент закрития меню не реагирует на клики

```js
'use stric';
$(function(){
    //Menu script
    let lastHideMenu;
    $('.menu').on('click', function(){
        lastHideMenu = $(this);
        $('body').append('<div id="close-menu" class="color-white">Х</div>');
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-active');
        let menuCoords = $(this).offset();
        $('#close-menu').css({'top': menuCoords.top+'px','left':menuCoords.left+'px'})
        $('#holder').toggleClass('show-holder'); 
    });
});
$('#close-menu').on('click', function(){
    console.log(true);
    $(this).remove;
    $(lastHideMenu).toggleClass('menu-is-active');
});
```

```css
#holder{
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.show-holder{
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    z-index: 20;
}
.menu-is-active{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#close-menu{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40pt;
    font-family: 'Asap', bold;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder"></div>
<div class="menu">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо бы клик вешать не на сам элемент, а на родителя, который не изменяется.
Это называется делегирование. Ибо написав так:

```
$('#close-menu').on('click', function(){
```

ты пытаешься повесить событие на элемент, которого нет. Логично, что он и не работает.

```js
'use strict';
$(function(){
    //Menu script
    let lastHideMenu;
    $('.menu').on('click', function(){
        lastHideMenu = $(this);
        $('body').append('<div id="close-menu" class="color-white">Х</div>');
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-active');
        let menuCoords = $(this).offset();
        $('#close-menu').css({'top': menuCoords.top+'px','left':menuCoords.left+'px'})
        $('#holder').toggleClass('show-holder'); 
    });
    
    $('body').on('click', '#close-menu', function(){
        console.log(true);
        $(this).remove;
        $(lastHideMenu).toggleClass('menu-is-active');
    });
});
```

```css
#holder{
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.show-holder{
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    z-index: 20;
}
.menu-is-active{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#close-menu{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40pt;
    font-family: 'Asap', bold;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder"></div>
<div class="menu">Test</div>
```

инфа о делегировании:

> Допустим на странице есть список (ul), на элементах которого
> необходимо обрабатывать событие click. Если после установки
> соответствующих обработчиков, в список будут добавлены новые элементы,
> то они уже не будут реагировать на «клики», поскольку непосредственно
> к новым элементам, обработчики прикреплены не были. Эта особенность
> может породить много проблем и коварных логических ошибок.
>
> Для таких случаев jQuery имеет возможность организовывать так
> называемую делегированную обработку событий. В этом случае, jQuery
> вместо заданного обработчика (в параметре handler) устанавливает
> собственный специальный обработчик. Причем он не устанавливается
> непосредственно на элементы, на которых необходимо обрабатывать
> события (назовем их inner-элементами), а на содержащие их элементы
> (назовем их outer-элементами. Получается, что inner находятся внутри
> outer). После того, как событие происходит на одном из элементов
> inner, оно начинает подниматься вверх по иерархии DOM. В какой то
> момент оно оказывается на одном из элементов outer, на котором
> срабатывает специально установленный обработчик, который проверяет,
> поднялось ли событие от одного из элементов inner. Если это так —
> запускается обработчик handler.
>
> В случае делегированной обработки, добавление новых inner-элементов внутрь outer-элементов, не нарушает работоспособность скрипта — события исправно обрабатываются, даже если они возникли на новых inner элементах.

[Прямая и делегированная обработка](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29)

Comment: но он же создается?

Comment: аа все понял спасибо)

Comment: @Horchynskyi кто "он"?

Comment: элемент. Ну в плане я же не сразу на него кликаю

Comment: @Horchynskyi по второму комменту я понял, что ты понял)) почитай цитатку на всякий случай или можешь по ссылке пройти прочитать

Comment: кстать а как теперь убрать блок при клике на него? закрить меню

Comment: все понял просто скобки не добавил)

Comment: о делегировании читал, и использовал только на чистом js) думал jq новые возможности вносит)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а насколько неправильно будет запихнуть обработчик закрытия меню в обработчик открытия?)